# ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

My AJAX is not working and I cannot figure out why. What am I missing??

ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined @ javascript.js:5

```
    function insapts(pin){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttpp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }else{ xmlhttpp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        xmlhttpp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttpp.readyState==4 && xmlhttpp.status==200){
                document.getElementById('apttimeins').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var url = "bridge3.php?pin="+pin;
        xmlhttpp.open("GET",url,false);
        xmlhttpp.send(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo. The `XMLHttpRequest` object is created with the local variable name `xmlhttpp`.

Change

```
 xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to

```
xmlhttpp.responseText;
//     ^ missing p
```

Comment: I can understand.. A fresh pair of eyes is always helpful :)